# Refresh part on my Page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to refresh this part of the page

```
<div class="refresh">
    <?php
    include("message.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

with this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function () {
            $('#refresh').empty();
            $('#refresh').load('message.php');
        }, 500);
</script>
```

Could you help me?

Comment: you should call message.php using ajax where ajax will fire after a regular time of interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
<div class="refresh">
```

To

```
<div id="refresh">
```

because you are using `id` selector in jquery to load the content.

Comment: depending on your usage, you could also alter your code to read `$('.refresh').empty()`, etc. This would trigger an event for all elements of class `refresh` - this would allow you to trigger an event on multiple elements of the same class at the same time, whilst maintaining distinct id's.

Comment: I always forgot which is the correct one between id and class. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you are using $('#refresh') then "#" represents the id, so change this

```
<div class="refresh">
```

to

```
<div id="refresh">
```

or change this

```
$('#refresh')
```

to

```
$('.refresh').
```